# Wagtail: View page log entries from PageLogEntry

Tags: python, django, wagtail

From the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/audit_log.html) it says that changes are automatically logged at the model level. I am in a situation where I need to check said logs but I am unable to import the `PageLogEntry` model. From the docs above I tried `from wagtail.core.models import PageLogEntry` but it's not importable. Looking at Wagtail's source code, I can see the specified module. I tried to also check my database for the table itself but nothing there either.

Is it that this functionality isn't in fact enabled automatically or is there something special that needs to be done to access the logs.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the development version of the docs. Page logging is added in Wagtail 2.10, which has not been released at the time of writing.